# How to update system clipboard when Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemSelection() returns null.

Tags: java

The following code:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemSelection().setContents(
    new StringSelection(a), null);
```

returns `null` because it is not supported on my Computer. But, I am wondering how I set my Computers selection if it does not support this. There has to be another way obviously. But how?

Comment: If Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemSelection() returns null, then your code would throw a NullPointerException, not return null.

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaDocs of [`Toolkit.getSystemSelection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getSystemSelection%28%29)

> Some platforms do not support a system selection `Clipboard`. On those platforms, this method will return `null`. **In such a case, an application is absolved from its responsibility to update the system selection Clipboard as described above**.

... so you do not need to worry in situations where `getSystemSelection()` returns `null`.

Comment: I don't think you understand. There is no way of highlighting or selecting text in this text area. I want to add it so you can Through Control + A. Then using getSysmtemSelection().setContents(contents);
But if their system doesn't support it, it won't work for them. In this case it doesn't work for me. But I can still copy through other programs and all. So there's obviously another way.